# CentOS7 systemctl calling ExecStop on reboot after my procceses are already killed

Tags: centos, centos7, systemd, systemctl

I have a systemd script which is as follows:

```
 [Unit]
 Description=My sites
 Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/etc/xxx/mySites start'
 ExecStop=/bin/bash -c '/etc/xxx/mySites stop'
 KillMode=none
 SendSIGKILL=no
 TimeoutStopUSec=5min
 TimeoutSec=5min
 TimeoutStopSec=5min


 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now...if I try to execute `sudo systemctl start  mySites.service` it seems the service is run and all my stuff is started correctly. If I do a `stop` it works too. Then, at OS boot, it also starts correct. The problem is on the OS shutdown. I am rebooting it and it seems like if the `ExecStop` WAS called too...but too late... I see in the logs that my processes all received a kill as I can see in my logs:

```
 signal 15, SIGTERM, received from process 1 userId 0
 si_code: 0, SI_USER, signal from kill(2), sigsend(2), raise(3C) or abort(3C)
 si_signo 15  si_errno 0
```

So..`ExecStop` seems to be being called too late because someone already killed the processes I originally started. Yet, I am already setting `Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target`.

I think the problem might be that my `ExecStop` may take longer than the default timeout, and hence systemd ends up sending SIGTERM. Now... I have set `KillMode=none`, `SendSIKKILL=no` and even all the possible timeouts to 5 minutes to `TimeoutStopUSec`, `TimeoutSec` and `TimeoutStopSec` (for sure my `ExecStop` takes less than 5 minutes).

Still no luck.

Any idea how can I fix this? I am running CentOS 7.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you have `Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target`? This is unnecessary and it might be causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that doesn't help. I tried and I got the exact same problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
[Unit]
Description=My sites
After=NetworkManager.service
Requires=NetworkManager.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/etc/xxx/mySites start'
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c '/etc/xxx/mySites stop'
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```